# TypeError: require is not a function

Tags: node.js, angular, electron

I am using Angular2 in electron app. I wanted to use the remote module of electron as described here.

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/remote.md#remote

When I write the following line in my typescript file, it throws an weird error

```
const {clipboard} = require('electron')
```

[image]

I know there are a lot of reference comes if I type that error in Google, but nothing helps. I tried all without any success.

**UPDATE:**

I have fixed the issue, simply updated the version of the systemJS to 0.19.41 and it worked. Previously it was 0.19.25. It will be great if anybody can explain why it was not working with the older version. I will accept the answer.

Comment: Are you using `system.js` or `webpack` ?

Comment: I am using SystemJS v0.19.25

Comment: then try `import` syntax, for `require` you need `commonjs`.

Comment: @AvneshShakya I have fixed the issue and updated the question. Please check. Thanks a lot for your prompt help.

Comment: Awesome and thanks for updating :) It will help for other also.

Comment: Post the solution as an answer and accept it.